# I can not unserialize this string

Tags: magento2, json, unserialize

I have saved this string into the database. when I trying to decode this string by below sentence this does not working.

```
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer

$this->serializer->unserialize($value);

[{"catagory_title":"lamn leg","catagory_value":"lamn_leg","delete":""},{"catagory_title":"lamn beef","catagory_value":"lamn_beef","delete":""}]
```

Comment: Magento version? do you get any error while running your code?

Comment: magento 2.2.2 yes at running time

Comment: post that error details in your question.